# How did consumer gas prices change in Latvia relative to Germany, following the substantial reduction of Russian imports in Latvia 2015-2021?

Tags: economy, germany, comparative-politics, gas, latvia

The 3 Baltic countries have [announced](https://www.ctvnews.ca/world/lithuania-cuts-off-russian-gas-imports-urges-eu-to-do-same-1.5846280) that they apparently import zero Russian gas now. More interestingly, this was a gradual reduction, e.g.

> In 2015, nearly 100 per cent of Lithuania's gas supplies derived from imports of Russian gas but the situation has changed drastically over the past years after the country built an off-shore LNG import terminal, launched in 2014, in the port city of Klaipeda. [...]
>
> Last year, some 26 per cent of Lithuania's gas supplies derived from deliveries from a Russian gas pipeline while 62 per cent came via Klaipeda's LNG terminal and the remaining 12 per cent were imported from a gas storage in neighbouring Latvia.

While bulk prices for gas are (alas) notoriously difficult to know due to contract secrecy, end-user prices can't be so easily hidden. So, how did end-user prices for natural gas change in Latvia relative to Germany, in that 2015-2021 time frame?

Comment: I'm not sure that the answer is relevant. Before 2022 and to some degree even after 2022, LNG has international markets. When *A* buys from *B* instead of *C*, and *D* snaps up the LNG from *C*, not much changes. When *C* is unable to sell because pipelines are shut and there is not enough liquefaction capacity, then markets react differently. From news reports, people are really concerned that Europe will start to buy up LNG elsewhere and to out-bid developing countries. (Just as Western Europe won't go hungry anytime soon, it will just out-bid other consumers.)

Comment: @o.m.: oh, I'm *not* trying to imply that if a small country did it, then the whole of EU could have done the same, without blowing up the LNG prices. I just want to know if they experienced troubles from doing it when it could be done, apparently more easily. The reason I'm asking for a comparison with Germany is that the latter mostly struck with pipelines, in the same timeframe, so that should factor out overall pricing fluctuations. Granted, I could have asked for comparison with the Czech Republic, or Hungary... as these are smaller countries, who rely on pipelines even more exclusively.